# JQuery error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I Have this script below that suppose to get values from input fields and then add them in a href link. but i keep getting this error in console:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   ?add-to-cart=7690&variation_id=8498&attribute_pa_color=gold

Here is the script:

```
    jQuery(document).on("click", ".variations_form.cart .variation_buttons_wrapper a", function(){
    // Get all the values needed for the URL
    var add_to_cart = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find( 'input[name="add-to-cart"]' ).val();
    var variation_id = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find( 'input[name="variation_id"]' ).val();    
    var pa_color = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    setTimeout(function(){
    // Craft the URL
    var link = jQuery("?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart + "&variation_id=" + variation_id + "&attribute_pa_color=" + pa_color);
    alert(link);
    }, 500); 
   });
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the jQuery object the wrong way.
If you are trying to craft a link do it this way:

```
var link = "?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart +
"&variation_id=" + variation_id +
"&attribute_pa_color=" + pa_color;
```

No need for the jQuery object here.

Comment: I will but apparently i have to wait 5 more minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the jQuery object when crafting the URL. Simply use it without the object.

```
var link = "?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart + "&variation_id=" + variation_id + "&attribute_pa_color=" + pa_color;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are passing querystring as jQuery selector. You need to create a valid selector for the same.

To add to href link, first select the link and get the URL

```
var link = $("#link").attr("href");
```

Then add the querystring to it

```
link += "?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart + "&variation_id=" + variation_id + "&attribute_pa_color=" + pa_color;
```

Suggestion:

If you are using a form, a shortcut way to get all fields as querystring is using jQuery `serialize` method. Example:

```
var queryString = $("#form").serialize();
```

Make sure all your form fields have name attributes.

Few words of wisdom:
Avoid to many `parent()` calls to reach the target element. You code will break if the DOM changes and nesting levels increases or decreases.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery("?add-to-cart="...)` is not a valid DOM selector, hence the error. You need to leave it as a string. Or even better, use [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/):

```
var link = jQuery.param({
  'add-to-cart': add_to_cart,
  'variation_id': variation_id 
})
```

---

BTW, instead of doing this:

`var add_to_cart = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find( 'input[name="add-to-cart"]' ).val();`

You could do something like this:

`jQuery(this).closest('.variations_form').find('input...')`

(replace `variations_form` with whatever parent class name you have)